# Python 3 Dice Sim issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am BRAND new to python because my new school requires it. I am used to c++ so I'm still learning the ropes. I'm trying to make a dice rolling simulator and I thought i was doing everything right but my code just won't work. Any tips or guides to help me learn would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import random

def roll(sides=6):
    num_rolled = random.randint(l,sides)
    return num_rolled

def main():
    sides = 6
    rolling = True
    while rolling:
        roll_again = input("Ready to roll? ENTER=Roll. Q=Quit. ")
    if roll_again.lower() != "q":
        num_rolled = roll(sides)
        print("You rolled a", num_rolled)
    else:
        rolling = False

    print("Thanks for playing!")

main()
```

This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\nomor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DiceRollingSim.py", line 20, in  main() File "C:\Users\nomor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DiceRollingSim.py", line 13, in main num_rolled = roll(sides) File "C:\Users\nomor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DiceRollingSim.py", line 4, in roll num_rolled = random.randint(l,sides) NameError: name 'l' is not defined

Comment: What's the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: I have no idea, but this is the error i get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nomor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DiceRollingSim.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\nomor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DiceRollingSim.py", line 13, in main
    num_rolled = roll(sides)
  File "C:\Users\nomor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DiceRollingSim.py", line 4, in roll
    num_rolled = random.randint(l,sides)
NameError: name 'l' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue...

```
num_rolled = random.randint(l,sides)
```

`l != 1`. You put an "l" instead of the number 1. Python thinks this is a variable which you haven't defined anywhere -> the error you get.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) randint takes two ints as parameters:

> random.randint(a, b)
>   Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

Next, look at these lines in your code.

```
 while rolling:
    roll_again = input("Ready to roll? ENTER=Roll. Q=Quit. ")
 if roll_again.lower() != "q":
    num_rolled = roll(sides)
    print("You rolled a", num_rolled)
 else:
    rolling = False
```

The `if-else` part needs to be indented inside of the while loop:

```
while rolling:
    roll_again = input("Ready to roll? ENTER=Roll. Q=Quit. ")
    if roll_again.lower() != "q":
        num_rolled = roll(sides)
        print("You rolled a", num_rolled)
    else:
        rolling = False
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Rookie mistake huh? This actually helped a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! We've all made rookie mistakes at some point :D